# Bootstrap : Date picker in a modal dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, modal-dialog

I m using Ace Admin Responsive theme to design my web application.
I need to open a date picker component in modal window. I used the way they do it in their theme. But when I click on the calendar, nothing shows. Or maybe it shows behind the modal dialog. It works well if I put the date picker outside the modal dialog.
Is it possible to user a date picker in a modal dialog?
My code :
To open my modal dialog :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-form" ng-click="clear()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Create a new Hike
</button>
```

In my dialog, date picker component:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-11">
        <!-- #section:plugins/date-time.datepicker -->
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control date-picker" id="id-date-picker-1" type="text" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar bigger-110"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Jquery code :

```
 $('.date-picker').datepicker({
                    autoclose: true,
                    todayHighlight: true
                })
                //show datepicker when clicking on the icon
                .next().on(ace.click_event, function(){
                    $(this).prev().focus();
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is showing behind the dialog, you need to set `z-index` of calender wrapper div element to a higher value than your modal. e.g. `9999`. 
You can use developer tools or firebug to inspect calender HTML. It should be in the end of body tag.